# Object mesh is not visible

Tags: outliner, visibility

Object mesh is not visible and in scene collection it appears in pale color.

How to make the object visible?

[image]

Comment: It could be that this object is part of a different collection, which is disabled.

Comment: No, disabling another collection will not make it invisible in this collection (which is obviously not disabled). And if only the object itself is disabled in viewport (like in my answer) it will be disabled in all collections so if there was another collection won't make a difference to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It can be set to *Disable in Viewports*. To check this, enable the toggle button for viewport visibility in the *Outliner* by clicking on the *Filter* (the funnel symbol) and enabling the monitor symbol there.

[image: viewport visibility]

[image: disabled-enabled]