# Rigify feet controls generating wrong

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

I'm having two problems: 1. the heel control is generating on the front of the foot instead of the back, and 2. the red rectangle control on the bottom of the foot is offset forward. I really don't know why either of these are happening. I'm super new to rigging but the rest of the rig seems fine from what I can tell. Any help would be very much appreciated on either how to fix my metarig so it won't generate like this, or, if that's not possible, on how to correct the controls after generation.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

And from my understanding this is what it's supposed to look like (foot centred, with heel control on back):

[image]

## Here is the .blend file
[image]

Comment: have you placed the heel bone of the metarig at the back of the foot on the floor? Here is the layout described: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/bone_positioning.html#id12

Comment: Yes, it's hard to see because the picture's at a weird angle and the bones are set to be visible in front but the heel bone is in position as shown in the guide.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. Hmm, hard to tell what causes this. Have you applied the *Scale* to the metarig? Can you share the file? (Feet and metarig should be enough if you don't want to share the whole model for some reason.)

Comment: I have applied the scale to the metarig, yes. I've just edited my post to include a .blend file. I did end up just uploading the bottom of the mesh and the metarig because it seems like blend-exchange requires you to give away the unrestricted rights for them to use anything you upload?? Seems insane and super scammy but anyways... Let me know if you need any other info or more of the mesh. Thank you for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your model is facing the wrong way. It turned by 180° along the Z-axis. The *Front* view (menu *View > Viewpoint > Front* or just <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>) shows in fact the back of the character.

This confuses Rigify (might be a bug or oversight) and causes the foot control to go in the wrong direction, namely backwards from the character's point of view.

To fix this you need to do few things

- rotate the model and the metarig. Select both and rotate them by 180° along the Z axis (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>) and apply the *Rotation* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in *Object* mode). This will fix the orientation.
- delete the *WGTS_rig v3* collection and all objects that it contains. These objects are the shapes for the control bones. Rigify will re-create them, this time without the offset. The collection is disabled in the viewport. You need to [enable the toggle button first](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277870/107598) (Filter dropdown > "monitor" icon), then you can delete them with a right-click > *Delete Hierarchy*.
- re-generate the rig with the Rigify button

(Sometimes the control bones are too small or too big or hidden inside the mesh. Then you still can adjust them in *Pose* mode in the *Viewport Display* section. But these changes get lost when you re-generate the rig.)

[image: Rigify rig]

Comment: Thank you so so much, I really appreciate it. That fixed everything. Helpful to know you can adjust control bones in Viewport Display too. :)