# Rigify: Generated Rig feet controls wrong alignment

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have a problem with Rigify. When I create a Rig from the Rigify metarig the alignment of the feet from the created Rig is incorrect. The feet are just pointing straight in the y-axis but they should point to the angle of the original foot bones.
Same with the foot_spin and foot_heel controllers.

Do you know how to fix that?

I already tried to edit the generated rig directly. That solved the alignment problem but once I parented it to the mesh, the mesh was distorted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I experimented for a while and just wanted to share my outcome. I found a solution for editing the generated rig directly. To avoid distortion of the mesh when parenting it to the corrected rig, it helps to set a new Rest Position.

However, this has an effect on some leg joints/controllers.

So, for me, the simplest way to address my original problem is just to edit the character's mesh and align the feet/shoes to the y-axis.

It's more of a workaround; I didn't find any solution for modifying the generated Rigify Rig itself without having these strange effects on the rest of the rig. It would still be helpful to know how to make changes to the alignment of the controllers.

Comment: It might be a limitation, bug, or requirement of Rigify. There is a [similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/310077/107598) where the character was rotated by 180°. So in the front view, you were looking at its back. Rigify then creates everything correctly except the feet. The controls are indeed rotated by 180° and not usable this way.